# How to make dynamic database selection injection-proof in C# SQL

Tags: c#, sql-injection

While trying make my code injection-proof, a previously functional area is now throwing an 'Invalid object name' error:

```
static void TestSQL(ref SqlConnection conn)
{
    var dataTable = new DataTable();

    // This line worked
    //var com = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [" + GetDatabaseName() + "].[dbo].[LOCATION]", conn);

    // These throw an error
    var com = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [@databaseName].[dbo].[LOCATION]", conn);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@databaseName", GetDatabaseName());

    using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(com))
    {
        adapter.Fill(dataTable); // -- Error occurs here --
    }
}
```

The exact message is

> "Invalid object name '@databaseName.dbo.LOCATION'."

It seems that AddWithValue doesn't like substituting that database name, which was kind of the point of this query. Somehow none of the dozens of injection threads I've read address making the database dynamic.

How can I be both injection-proof AND maintain my requirement of dynamic database selection? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Parameters are for values only, not table or database names

Comment: Look into `QUOTENAME`.

Comment: Why do you think you need to pass the database or table name as a "parameter" ?

Comment: @AakashM won't help at all. If the *query string* containts `'; `, the query text end right there

Comment: @TS- you don't need to make the database "dynamic". Just use a different connection string. Perhaps you should use an ORM and let *it* construct the database queries

Comment: Why are you passing a *connection* to the method and why is it *ref*? In general you shouldn't keep around a connection any more than necessary. Global and long-lived connections are a *bad* idea. There's no reusability benefit. ADO.NET takes care to reset and pool connections when you "close" them so that you don't have to wait to reopen them, and no *locks* or *transactions* linger to cause blocking

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I'll confess, I created this method to make the problem easier to see. This was happening in another, larger method that had a lot of junk that was not relevant to the problem. The ref connection was a quck-and-dirty way to make this example, I'm not keeping it like that.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos not if the `;` is in a **quoted identifier**, which is what `QUOTENAME` produces.. Try it: you can `CREATE DATABASE [hello;world] --add suitable filegroups etc` and then `select * from [hello;world].sys.tables` with absolutely no problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

specify the database name when you create the connection and not in the SQL

Comment: Perfect! The connection I was using could technically access those tables, but I'm better off making a new connection in this case.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you do something like this:

```
var com = new SqlCommand($"SELECT * FROM [{GetDatabaseName()}].[dbo].[LOCATION]", conn);
```

This works in C# 6

Else you can use the normal way:

```
var com = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [" + GetDatabaseName() + "].[dbo].[LOCATION]", conn);
```

Comment: Because it's no different at all? Whether you use `" + GetDatabaseName() " +` or `String.Format("...[{0}] ..",GetDatabaseName() ) or  `$"SELECT * FROM [{GetDatabaseName()}]` the code is the same. If `GetDatabaseName()` returns an unexpected character, you get a syntax error or injection

Comment: That second line is what I had been doing, and it *worked*, but it it's not injection-proof. I want both of those things.

Comment: @TS- both lines are (almost) identical. None is injection-proof. Why do you think you need to pass the *database name* like this? Why not *connect* to the appropriate database? Databases and tables aren't *parameters*. They are the fundamental building blocks

Comment: True none are SQL injection proof. But isn't GetDatabaseName() your own method? It's not an input from a user

Comment: @Panagiotis - Yes it's different, because his issue is this: "Invalid object name '@ databaseName.dbo.LOCATION'.", @ databaseName was not changing, that's why I suggested the above (although I didn't notice his commented code)

Comment: @CliveCiappara and your answer isn't going to fix anything. The problem is how to pass the database name as a "parameter". The answer is *not* to construct the query by concatenating strings. Interpolation is essentially the same as writing `String.Format("...{0}...",whatever);`. Any bad string is going to cause injection